# Rails with postgresql: extract field from time is not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activesupport

I have a problem with ordering a collection by hour. But first things first.

Project details:

```
Rails version             5.1.3
Ruby version              2.4.1-p111 (x86_64-linux)
Database adapter          postgresql
```

This is how my collection looks like:

```
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ad2690
  id: 1,
  start: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 01:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 02:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:39 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:25 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abcf98
  id: 2,
  start: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 02:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 03:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:39 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:25 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ad23c0
  id: 3,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 03:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 04:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:39 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ad1e70
  id: 4,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 04:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 05:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ad1470
  id: 5,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 05:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 06:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ad0bd8
  id: 6,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 06:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 07:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acfdc8
id: 7,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 07:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acf7b0
  id: 8,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 08:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 09:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acf198
  id: 9,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 09:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 10:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acee00
  id: 10,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 10:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 11:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1aceb80
  id: 11,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 11:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ace838
  id: 12,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 12:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1ace4c8
  id: 13,
start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 13:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 14:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acdde8
  id: 14,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 14:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 15:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acd758
  id: 15,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 15:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 16:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acd168
  id: 16,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 16:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 17:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:26 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acce20
  id: 17,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 17:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 18:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1acc678
  id: 18,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 18:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 19:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abfb30
  id: 19,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 19:00:00 +03 +03:00,
stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 20:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abf220
  id: 20,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 20:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 21:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abea78
  id: 21,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 21:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 22:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abe500
  id: 22,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 22:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 23:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abdf10
  id: 23,
  start: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 23:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 00:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>,
 #<DeliveryTimeslot:0x00562dd1abd3f8
  id: 24,
  start: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 00:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  stop: Sun, 02 Jan 2000 01:00:00 +03 +03:00,
  created_at: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 17:57:40 +03 +03:00,
  updated_at: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 12:40:27 +03 +03:00>]
```

Both `start` and `stop` columns are t.time in schema (so records are `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`).

What I want to do is to order them by hour and I have to do it using SQL statements.

So I have tried this:

```
DeliveryTimeslot.all.order("EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) DESC").map(&:id)
```

and I expected to get array like this:

```
[23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 24]
```

but instead I've got this:

```
[2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

My thought was that this is because three records (with ids 1, 2 and 24) have a different start date (2nd of january while rest of them have 1st of january). Isn't the query I've wrote above supposed to extract hour from time type record? Is it really because of date? IDK why this is not working and basically I can't change anything in DB. Any hints what I am doing wrong? Any hints for make it without any changes in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It worked with my existing application

Try it

`DeliveryTimeslot.all.order('start DESC').sort_by {|item| item.start.to_date}.map{|item| item.id}`

Comment: This is the way faster than my approach :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `DeliveryTimeslot.all.order("start DESC").map(&:id)`

Comment: The result is the same as from my query

'[2, 1, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]'

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I believe the answer is that this issue is caused by construction of db itself. In postgresql doc:(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-datetime.html)
they say:

> We do not recommend using the type time with time zone

...and ActiveRecord is messing somehow with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.

A colleague told me to sort it by extracted hour.
In psql it looks ok:

```
kriseqsdb=# SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) AS extracted_hour, * FROM delivery_timeslots ORDER BY EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) DESC;
 extracted_hour | id |  start   |   stop   |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----------------+----+----------+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
             23 |  2 | 23:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:39.981764 | 2017-03-16 09:40:25.960571
             22 |  1 | 22:00:00 | 23:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:39.960375 | 2017-03-16 09:40:25.738402
             21 | 24 | 21:00:00 | 22:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.381005 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.558225
             20 | 23 | 20:00:00 | 21:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.362648 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.485668
             19 | 22 | 19:00:00 | 20:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.347286 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.413084
             18 | 21 | 18:00:00 | 19:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.329297 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.340032
             17 | 20 | 17:00:00 | 18:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.309307 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.267091
             16 | 19 | 16:00:00 | 17:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.291424 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.194525
             15 | 18 | 15:00:00 | 16:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.261229 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.122137
             14 | 17 | 14:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.244531 | 2017-03-16 09:40:27.049617
             13 | 16 | 13:00:00 | 14:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.228901 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.977144
             12 | 15 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.2118   | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.904671
             11 | 14 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.194678 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.832177
             10 | 13 | 10:00:00 | 11:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.175353 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.759804
              9 | 12 | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.159382 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.687357
              8 | 11 | 08:00:00 | 09:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.144921 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.614746
              7 | 10 | 07:00:00 | 08:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.127898 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.542091
              6 |  9 | 06:00:00 | 07:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.106023 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.469586
              5 |  8 | 05:00:00 | 06:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.082284 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.397126
              4 |  7 | 04:00:00 | 05:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.06161  | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.324512
              3 |  6 | 03:00:00 | 04:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.046009 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.251731
              2 |  5 | 02:00:00 | 03:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.03066  | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.178915
              1 |  4 | 01:00:00 | 02:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:40.015266 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.106172
              0 |  3 | 00:00:00 | 01:00:00 | 2016-10-05 14:57:39.996529 | 2017-03-16 09:40:26.033393
(24 rows)
```

and so it does via rails console:

```
DeliveryTimeslot.connection.select_all("SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) AS extracted_hour, * FROM delivery_timeslots ORDER BY EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) DESC")
=>
[23.0, 2, "23:00:00", "00:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:39.981764", "2017-03-16 09:40:25.960571"],
   [22.0, 1, "22:00:00", "23:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:39.960375", "2017-03-16 09:40:25.738402"],
   [21.0, 24, "21:00:00", "22:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.381005", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.558225"],
   [20.0, 23, "20:00:00", "21:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.362648", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.485668"],
   [19.0, 22, "19:00:00", "20:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.347286", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.413084"],
   [18.0, 21, "18:00:00", "19:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.329297", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.340032"],
   [17.0, 20, "17:00:00", "18:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.309307", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.267091"],
   [16.0, 19, "16:00:00", "17:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.291424", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.194525"],
   [15.0, 18, "15:00:00", "16:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.261229", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.122137"],
   [14.0, 17, "14:00:00", "15:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.244531", "2017-03-16 09:40:27.049617"],
   [13.0, 16, "13:00:00", "14:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.228901", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.977144"],
   [12.0, 15, "12:00:00", "13:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.2118", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.904671"],
   [11.0, 14, "11:00:00", "12:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.194678", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.832177"],
   [10.0, 13, "10:00:00", "11:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.175353", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.759804"],
   [9.0, 12, "09:00:00", "10:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.159382", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.687357"],
   [8.0, 11, "08:00:00", "09:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.144921", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.614746"],
   [7.0, 10, "07:00:00", "08:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.127898", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.542091"],
   [6.0, 9, "06:00:00", "07:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.106023", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.469586"],
   [5.0, 8, "05:00:00", "06:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.082284", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.397126"],
   [4.0, 7, "04:00:00", "05:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.06161", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.324512"],
   [3.0, 6, "03:00:00", "04:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.046009", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.251731"],
   [2.0, 5, "02:00:00", "03:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.03066", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.178915"],
   [1.0, 4, "01:00:00", "02:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:40.015266", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.106172"],
   [0.0, 3, "00:00:00", "01:00:00", "2016-10-05 14:57:39.996529", "2017-03-16 09:40:26.033393"]
```

In that case it is ok for me as this was my main concern. But to be clear about my question and get proper array I just mapped it by extracted_hour:

```
DeliveryTimeslot.connection.select_all("SELECT EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) AS extracted_hour, * FROM delivery_timeslots ORDER BY EXTRACT (HOUR FROM start) DESC").rows.map { |row| row[0].to_i }
```

and basically got what I've asked about.

```
    => [23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```